# How to list items with the same id in Async Storage in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new to React native, I'm creating a online store app my problem is : when the person selects a repeated item it does not appear in the cart it just updates , I would like it to include and list in the cart this repeated item ... as I said I'm new to react native, but I believe the problem is in the listing and not in the register ...

Function add in cart in AddCart.js

```
const addToCart = async (id) => {
    
    let itemArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cartItems');
    itemArray = JSON.parse(itemArray);
    if (itemArray) {
      let array = itemArray;
      
      array.push(id);

             
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(array));
        ToastAndroid.show(
          'Item Added Successfully to cart',
          ToastAndroid.SHORT,
        );
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    } else {
      let array = [];
      array.push(id);
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(array));
        ToastAndroid.show(
          'Item Added Successfully to cart',
          ToastAndroid.SHORT,
        );
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    }
  };
```

MyCart.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,  
  Alert
  } from 'react-native';
  import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
    
  const MyCart = ({navigation}) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  
   useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        getDataFromDB();              
    });

    return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);
  
    const getDataFromDB = async id =>{
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cartItems');

    items = JSON.parse(items);
    if(items.length===0){
      Alert.alert(  
        "Ops",
        "The cart is empty",
        [
          {
            text: "Ok",
            onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Home'),
            style: "cancel"
          }
        ]
      );
      }else{
    let productData = [];
    if (items) {
      Items.forEach(data => {
        if (items.includes(data.id)) {
          productData.push(data);
          return;
        }
      });
      setProduct(productData);
      getTotal(productData);        
       } else {
      setProduct(false);
      getTotal(false);
      
    }
   }
   };
   const renderProducts = (data, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={data.key}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProductInfo', {productID: data.id})}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 100,
          marginVertical: 6,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '30%',
            height: 100,
            padding: 14,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: COLOURS.backgroundLight,
            borderRadius: 10,
            marginRight: 22,
          }}>
          <Image
            source={data.productImage}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            height: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
          }}>
          <View style={{}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 14,
                maxWidth: '100%',
                color: COLOURS.black,
                fontWeight: '600',
                letterSpacing: 1,
              }}>
              {data.productName},
            </Text>
            <View
              style={{
                marginTop: 4,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                opacity: 0.6,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: '400',
                  maxWidth: '85%',
                  marginRight: 4,
                }}>
                R$ {data.productPrice2}.00 , {data.id}
              </Text>
              <Text>
                
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 100,
                  marginRight: 20,
                  padding: 4,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: COLOURS.backgroundMedium,
                  opacity: 0.5,
                }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="minus"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: COLOURS.backgroundDark,
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <Text>1</Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 100,
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  padding: 4,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: COLOURS.backgroundMedium,
                  opacity: 0.5,
                }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="plus"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: COLOURS.backgroundDark,
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItemFromCart(data.id)}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="delete-outline"
                style={{
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: COLOURS.backgroundDark,
                  backgroundColor: COLOURS.backgroundLight,
                  padding: 8,
                  borderRadius: 100,
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
    
    };

   return (
    <View> {product ? product.map(renderProducts) : null} </View>
  );
};

export default MyCart;
```

I would be grateful to help me

Comment: `Items.forEach(data => {
        if (items.includes(data.id)) {
          productData.push(data);
          return;
        }
      });` - what is this?

Comment: I'm taking the cart data and storing it in "Items", then I compare them with my database if it's ok I store it in the 'productData' array

Comment: I mean you have only the variable named "items", not "Items" - and you don't show where "Items" are defined, seems like this code is not correct, right now it will crash due variable "Items" is not defined

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, it's "items" not "Items"